# Pass custom parameter to returnurl from angular oidc-client

Tags: angular7, identityserver4, oidc-client

I'm trying to pass a custom parameter to returnURL used in login page IdentityServer 4 from angular oidc-client.

Based on the parameter i receive from the returnURL I want to bypass the login website and redirect them to IDP. I'm intending to add the parameter to a specific page from angular and from there I want to redirect to login.

Below links talks about them but those I'm not able to follow. Can you guys please help. Thanks in advance.

[Pass custom parameter to returnUrl used in login page Identity Server 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153104/pass-custom-parameter-to-returnurl-used-in-login-page-identity-server-4/58274658#58274658)

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/909

C# AccountController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);


    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
        return ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);

    return View(vm);
}
```

Angular auth.service.ts

```
const settings: any = {
  authority: environment.oauthUrl,
  client_id: 'website',
  redirect_uri: `${environment.applicationUrl}/auth.html`,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.applicationUrl}`,
  response_type: 'id_token token',
  scope: 'openid profile email profile nucleus',

  silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.applicationUrl}/silent-renew.html`,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,

  monitorSession: true,
  checkSessionInterval: 2000,

  revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,

  changePasswordUrl: `${environment.oauthUrl}/Manage/ChangePassword?returnUrl=${environment.applicationUrl}`
};
```

I expect a parameter from returnurl and add a condition like this in Login method of AccountController.cs.

```
if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly || returnUrl.Contains("customparameter"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Incase if someone is looking for an answer.
I have added route so that I can get clientid from angular app.

app.routes.ts

```
 { path: 'client/:id', component:ClientComponent }
```

In the client.component.ts

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const clientId=this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    if(clientId!=null) {
      this.authService.startSigninClient(clientId);
    }
  }
```

In the auth.service.ts

```
startSigninClient(clientid: string) {
    this.mgr.signinRedirect({
      extraQueryParams: {       
          client: clientid
      },
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Now when I open angular_app/client/clientid it redirects to client.component.ts and I'm calling signinredirect in which I'm adding extraQueryParams which is getting the value and sending a redirect_url from client oidc to dotnet authorization endpoint(accountcontroller.cs in my case) based on which I'm doing my required logic to handle different client logins and idps.